# Releasing for Ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, linux, ubuntu, debian

I've built a few pieces of C++ software I want to release for Ubuntu. What ways are there and what can you recommend? Is building [.deb](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging) files and setting up an [apt repo](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository) for them the best way? What about `make install`, is it considered an acceptable way to install software?

By far simplest for me, and perhaps most transparent for the user, would be to just have a github repository in which one could run `make install` to get all programs installed at one go.

Do I always install the binaries into `/usr/bin`?

One of the programs contains Python 3 library code, should that be installed in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`? (I don't want to create a `pip` package, that would make the installation harder -- and waste more of my time.) The program also contains Python 3 examples/tutorials intended for the user to tweak and learn from, where do I install those? Do I create a `~/my-prog-tutorial-dir/` to put them in? If so: how should I name that directory?

**Edit:** if I simply release the statically linked binaries in a tarball, what will break eventually? Libc? Are there any major application APIs that usually change between Ubuntu LTSs? I only use pthreads, X11 and OpenGL so I suspect statically linked binaries could be a fairly stable option?

Comment: Not everybody has permissions to install into `/usr/bin`. So your default may be `/usr/bin` but you should make it configurable enough to use other locations. Most C++ source uses another level of build tools (autotools) and the software is installed with `./configure && make && make test && sudo make install`

Comment: See [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu)

Comment: I, for example, distribute my software as plain archived executables that can be downloaded from the official [website](https://brute.tk)

Comment: @ForceBru: how is that working for you? Does you software usually work across LTSs? What dependencies do you have? Write it up as an answer.

Comment: I just read your edit. When you release a binary, you have to be concerned about ABI and how the implementation interacts with the rest of the system, not API. OpenGL is very stable with this respect and there is no point in static linking it. Moreover if you static link it, what implementation are you going to use? I do not have a clear vision about X11 and pthread stability. C++ itself [could be problematic](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/), but in your case static linking libstdc++ should be enough, unless you are providing C++ libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332185/releasing-for-ubuntu#comment62283804_37332185) to expand my comment in an answer, and so I do.

The project I was talking about is called [Woodpecker hash Bruteforce](https://brute.tk), and I distribute it as plain archived executables for Mac OS, Windows and Linux.

Woodpecker hash Bruteforce has only two dependencies I have to care about (the users don't need to install anything): OpenSSL and Botan - libraries to do hashing. I've got two virtual machines on my Mac where I build the project and several scripts to automate the process. I'm using Docker (in collaboration with VirtualBox) and VMware Fusion.

Above I said the users don't need to worry about any third-party libraries because everything's linked statically with the executable: you just download the appropriate file from the official website, unarchive it (if needed), `sudo chmod +x` the executable and that's it!

This works on any version of Linux, including Ubuntu (this is where I perform the build) and Kali Linux.

Comment: That sounds like a perfectly simple and neat way to release! I've read a number of times online that people have trouble running precompiled Linux binaries. Is that something of the past, or does that mostly apply on dynamically linked binaries? I assume you build 32-bit x86 versions only? Most people use x86_64 hardware these days, but perhaps that is of little to no importance to your application?

Comment: @JonasByström, well, I've never had any troubles running my program on various Linuxes. Currently I'm building only 32-bit binaries for Linux, because nobody requested 64-bit ones, but this can be done with another line in my scripts that control the build process.

Comment: As I also reported in my answer, static linking has good portability: I saw this method failing just a few times, with very old binaries (e.g., compiled on pre 2.0 kernels) or if they were accessing devices. Dinamic linking is more complicated, especially with C++ software, as you will soon see ABI incompatibilities, unless you ship all the dependencies and scripts to help the linker use them.
Please, have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254735/are-c-static-libraries-frowned-upon#comment513712_254735 and following comments to understand why I discourage it.

Comment: @GiulioPaci: your and ForceBru's answers and googling has only revealed dogma regarding the benefits of dynamic, and as static linking is *very* easy and presumably stable that's my choice.

Comment: @JonasByström: pros and cons of dynamic vs staric linking is not a dogma. They both have costs that should be considered on a case by case basis. If you want to deliver closed source software and are not planning to do maintainance work, static linking is the only reasonable solution. This is particularly true if you are not targeting a specific distribution. If this is the case I suggest you to add that information to your question, otherwise this is not the right answer.

Comment: @GiulioPaci, what do you mean by 'are not planning to do maintainance work'? Yes, my software is closed-source, but I _am_ doing maintenance work successfully (e.g. fixing bugs, adding new features, upgrading libraries, etc).

Comment: @ForceBru: I mean that you will not do maintainance forever. But you are also targeting multiple distributions, while the question is about Ubuntu. If the question was "What is the best way to release closed source software for Linux?", then your answer is more correct than mine. With Ubuntu constraint, it is more correct only if no maintainance work is planned, as building Debian packages does not add much work. Moreover if LGPL libraries are involved, respecting the license with static linking adds complexity to the release process, as you have to grant relinking possibility to the users.

Comment: @ForceBru: I just realised that my last comment is still ambiguos. I had not your project in mind when I mentioned "not planning to do maintainance work", I had in mind some closed source software that I used in the past (e.g., videogames) that do not receive much maintainance after the release, as developers are usually moving to other projects.

Comment: @GiulioPaci: The software is a game, but not closed source. I'm releasing the binaries for convenience.

Comment: @JonasByström: then I do not think you are taking the best possible decision, given that you are targeting Ubuntu. The best option, from user perspective, is to have the software in Ubuntu. If you remove the "Ubuntu" word from your question, still you should follow the first two points of my answer and then either proceed according to my answer or provide a static build (with OpenGL dinamically loaded, as you want your users to be able to use hardware accelerated implementations) or proceed according to my answer or both.

Answer (score 2):

In general, building a binary package will make your software much easier for your users to install and keep up to date.  The same goes for python packages.  There are generally tools to generate apt packages from pip packages, so you can just list your python code as a dependency of your binary package(s).

You may see packaging and installers as a waste of your time, but only providing a source distribution wastes your users' time.  Users don't want to constantly have to check github for new versions, and they often don't want to have to install all of your build dependencies if they just want to use your software.  If your software is targeted towards developers this may be less of an issue, but it's still extra work that your users have to go through.

As for examples, the general convention is to put those in /usr/share/doc/myprogram/samples or a samples directory in your python package.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to release software **for** Ubuntu depends on the software itself and its target audience, as [Miles Budnek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37332467/3021900) already pointed out.

Your goal is to lower the barriers to software usage. If you are targeting developers of your software (i.e., you develop source files that are supposed to be edited by others) or you are developing piece of code supposed to be included in other projects (e.g., gnulib), probably it is best to just provide sources and documentation.

In any other case that I currently imagine (including when you are targeting developers), providing precompiled binaries is a better option. In this case the optimal solution would be to have the software **in** Ubuntu. In this case [How to get my software into Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16446/how-to-get-my-software-into-ubuntu) provides a lot of useful information, as suggested by [Mark K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332185/releasing-for-ubuntu#comment62183214_37332185).

Getting software into Debian or Ubuntu can be difficult and may require a large amount of time (you have to respect a lot of policies that you may not be aware of and you have to find a sponsor) and you will soon learn that a key point is to use a decent and popular build system for your software (e.g., autotools, cmake, distutils, ...) as mentioned in the [Debian Upstream Guide](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide). Being compliant with the guide will also be beneficial for users of other distributions.

In general I suggest to proceed in this order:

1. provide sources;
2. use a common build system (from the point of view of system administrators, i.e., people installing the software, autotools works best in my experience for Posix systems);
3. create a binary package (please keep in mind that you have to maintain it or your users will likely encounter binary incompatibilities);
4. add the package in private repository (I suggest [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) for this task);
5. try to get the package in the distribution of choice (please keep in mind maintainance costs).

Another option that I do not suggest, is to provide statically linked builds. This reduces the possibility of binary incompatibilities, but augment the costs of bug fixing (e.g., if the bug is in a dependency) and security, as explained in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254735/are-c-static-libraries-frowned-upon#comment513712_254735) and following comments. Another reason to avoid static linking is if several implementations of the same ABI exists, in order to  exploit hardware acceleration (e.g., OpenGL), but you can also mix static and dynamic linking.

Finally you may also provide a container, like [docker](https://www.docker.com/), to ship your software and all its dependencies: your users will just need docker to run your application very portably. However it is probably overkill in most situations and if it is a practical solution or not depends on your application and target audience.